# Would a [feedback-featured] tag be helpful here on meta?

Tags: discussion, feedback

[image]

Recently I have noticed a lot of feedback requests from the Team on different interesting topics like these for example:

- [Help us test the advantages of using a CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90073/help-us-test-the-advantages-of-using-a-cdn)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/help-us-test-and-vet-stackid-stack-exchange-openid
- [Feedback requested: Similar Questions displayed in sidebar on /ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91568/feedback-requested-similar-questions-displayed-in-sidebar-on-ask)
- [Help Choose the Speakers and Talks for Dev Days 2011 [London]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89728/help-choose-the-speakers-and-talks-for-dev-days-2011-london)

It's difficult to follow this kind of requests because they lack a common tag and the questions, if not marked as favorite, are quickly buried by the other "common" questions.
Because the number of team member is getting really fat, it will be harder to keep track of your important requests of feedback in the future.
The [feedback](/questions/tagged/feedback) tag is mixing all the f[eedback flavors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) and it's not helpful to separate *Your* feedback questions from *Our* feedback questions<sup>*</sup>.

**Proposal:**
Is it possible to have a [feedback-featured](/questions/tagged/feedback-featured) in red or something similar to help us to follow these kind of feedback requests?
I think it would be an interesting tag to follow here on meta and it will help us to quickly reach your feedback requests in one click.

<sup>I'm tagging this question with [feedback](/questions/tagged/feedback)</sup>

Comment: +1, though I think this would only really help if the tag had special Community User bumping behaviour to keep it more visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not [`feedback` and `featured`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback+featured)? As an added benefit, [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) auto-expires after 30 days, so the feedback request will quieten down when it's in all likelihood obsolete.